# Count The Number of Duplicate Values during the preceding timeperiod

Tags: pyspark

I am looking to count how many duplicate values there are in a previous time period (24 hours to make it simple).

For example in this data set

[image]

I am looking to come up with values such as this

[image]

Here is some how to create the below dataframe

```
data = [("5812", "2020-12-27T17:28:32.000+0000"),("5812", "2020-12-25T17:35:32.000+0000"), ("5812", "2020-12-25T13:04:05.000+0000"), ("7999", "2020-12-25T09:23:01.000+0000"),("5999","2020-12-25T07:29:52.000+0000"), ("5814", "2020-12-25T12:23:05.000+0000"),  ("5814", "2020-12-25T11:52:57.000+0000"), ("5814", "2020-12-24T11:00:57.000+0000") ,("5999", "2020-12-24T07:29:52.000+0000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

I have been using windowed functions to get things such as distinct counts, sums etc, but I can't quite figure out how to get a count of duplicate values over the same time period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this step by step

1. Cast column *timestamp* to `TimestampType` format.
2. Create a column  of `collect_list` of *mcc* (say *mcc_list*) in the last 24 hours using window with `range between interval 24 hours and current row` frame.
3. Create a column of set/unique collection of *mc_list* (say *mcc_set*) using `array_distinct` function. This column could also be created using `collect_set` over the same window in step 2.
4. For each value of *mcc_set*, get its count in the *mcc_list*. Duplicated *mcc* value will have a count of > 1 so we can filter it. After that, the array will only contain the duplicated *mcc*, use `size` to count how many mcc are duplicated in the last 24 hours.

These steps put into a code could be like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = (df
      .withColumn('ts', F.col('timestamp').cast(TimestampType()))
      .withColumn('mcc_list', F.expr("collect_list(mcc) over (order by ts range between interval 24 hours preceding and current row)"))
      .withColumn('mcc_set', F.array_distinct('mcc_list'))
      .withColumn('dups', F.expr("size(filter(transform(mcc_set, a -> size(filter(mcc_list, b -> b = a))), c -> c > 1))"))
    #   .drop(*['ts', 'mcc_list', 'mcc_set']))
)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +----+----------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------+----+
# |mcc |timestamp                   |ts                 |mcc_list                            |mcc_set                 |dups|
# +----+----------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------+----+
# |5812|2020-12-27T17:28:32.000+0000|2020-12-27 17:28:32|[5812]                              |[5812]                  |0   |
# |5812|2020-12-25T17:35:32.000+0000|2020-12-25 17:35:32|[5999, 7999, 5814, 5814, 5812, 5812]|[5999, 7999, 5814, 5812]|2   |
# |5812|2020-12-25T13:04:05.000+0000|2020-12-25 13:04:05|[5999, 7999, 5814, 5814, 5812]      |[5999, 7999, 5814, 5812]|1   |
# |5814|2020-12-25T12:23:05.000+0000|2020-12-25 12:23:05|[5999, 7999, 5814, 5814]            |[5999, 7999, 5814]      |1   |
# |5814|2020-12-25T11:52:57.000+0000|2020-12-25 11:52:57|[5999, 7999, 5814]                  |[5999, 7999, 5814]      |0   |
# |7999|2020-12-25T09:23:01.000+0000|2020-12-25 09:23:01|[5814, 5999, 7999]                  |[5814, 5999, 7999]      |0   |
# |5999|2020-12-25T07:29:52.000+0000|2020-12-25 07:29:52|[5999, 5814, 5999]                  |[5999, 5814]            |1   |
# |5814|2020-12-24T11:00:57.000+0000|2020-12-24 11:00:57|[5999, 5814]                        |[5999, 5814]            |0   |
# |5999|2020-12-24T07:29:52.000+0000|2020-12-24 07:29:52|[5999]                              |[5999]                  |0   |
# +----+----------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------+----+
```

You can drop unwanted columns afterwards.

Comment: This works, it appears my expected output was incorrect. Thank you so much!